# Why is reverse() on specific slice of a list not working?

Tags: python

I have a list, `a = [0,1,2,3,4,5]`.

I'm trying to reverse the slice `a[1:4]`, with `a[1:4].reverse()`. However, the value of `a` does not change. Why does this happen?

Note: I don't want to know how to make this work - rather, why this happens.

Comment: ```a[1:4].reverse()``` is same like ```a[1:4:-1]```

Comment: `a[1:4]` creates a brand new list object, of length 3. `.reverse()` then reverses that new list. And then the new list is thrown away, because nothing references it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be easiest to see with a little monitor wrapper (subclass) of `list`:

```
class ListWrapper(list):
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        print(f'__setitem__ was called on {id(self)}')
        super(ListWrapper, self).__setitem__(key, value)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        print(f'Get Item was called on {id(self)}')
        n = ListWrapper(super(ListWrapper, self).__getitem__(item))
        print(f'New id is {id(n)}')
        return n

    def reverse(self):
        print(f'Reversed Called on {id(self)}')
        super(ListWrapper, self).reverse()
```

Essentially the `ListWrapper` incorporates a few print statements among the methods used in this operation:

```
a = ListWrapper([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print('ID of `a` is', id(a))
a[1:4].reverse()
print('ID of `a` is', id(a))
```

The output of which is:

```
ID of `a` is 2002062741728
__getitem__ was called on 2002062741728
New id is 2002062745088  # Notice the ID is different
reverse called on 2002062745088  # Reverse is called on this new object
ID of `a` is 2002062741728  # The id of `a` has not changed
```

We have no way to access the value with id `2002062745088` since we don't have a variable anywhere which contains this information.

---

In response to one of the questions in the comments: "If this is the case, then why does a[1:4] = [3,2,1] change the value of a?"

Let's also look at that operation:

```
a = ListWrapper([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
print('ID of `a` is', id(a))
a[1:4] = [3, 2, 1]
print('ID of `a` is', id(a))
```

The output of which is:

```
ID of `a` is 2760760102160
__setitem__ was called on 2760760102160
ID of `a` is 2760760102160
```

Notice that `a` has the same `id` throughout. And neither of the functions in the previous example were called (`__getitem__` and `reverse`). As such, the update happened to the list `a` and it's results are accessible.

Answer (score 2):

`a[1:4]` creates a new list. You called `reverse` on this new list, not `a`

Answer (score 2):

Here's what `a[1:4].reverse()` actually does:

- create a sublist (slice) of `a`, so `a[1:4]` == `[1, 2, 3]`
- reverse that list in-place, so it's now `[3, 2, 1]`
- throw that list away because you didn't ask it to do anything with it

Comment: If this is the case, then why does a[1:4] = [3,2,1] change the value of a?

Comment: Because you've assigned it back to a slice of ```a``` (the left hand side of the assignment).

Comment: There is a difference between `__getitem__` and `__setitem__` in python. Assigning to the slice `a[1:4]` will call a different operation than getting the slice `a[1:4]`. @RyanFu

Comment: It has to do with how the syntax is interpreted/compiled. You can think of a lot of syntax as equivalent to some method call. It just so happens that `a[1:4]` makes a new list, and `a[1:4] = b` edits the original list.

Answer (score 0):

`list.reverse()` is an in-place function that modifies the original list.

When you call `a[1:4]`, `a[1:4]` is only a value that got sliced from `a`, and no container, i.e. a variable, is holding the variable.

The in-place modifying function is modifying the newly created list, that is, the returned sliced list. However, since there is no container holding it, nor does it point back to the original `a`, it will be lost.

Reference documentation [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists)

Answer (score 0):

You are actually working  on `a[1:4]` and not `a`. Since you didn't reference it, the list is thrown away.

See:

```
>>> a[1:4].reverse()
#==== No output ====
>>> d=a[1:4]
>>> d.reverse()
[3, 2, 1]
```

When the list was not referenced, it was discarded. But when you assigned it to a variable `d`, you can see the result.